# Do while not looping?

Tags: c, do-while

I am a beginner who has started learning C. I want to write a program using C which helps users to input nos. as much as they want and once they are done, the program shows the no. of positive, negative and zeros entered. I am trying to do this using do-while lopp. It is executing once, but it isnt going on loop. I want to know what am i doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a,p=0,n=0,z=0;
    char c;

    do
    {
       printf("enter a no.\n");
       scanf("%d", &a);

       if (a>0)
       {
            p++;
       }
       else if (a==0)
       {
            z++;
       }
       else if(a<0)
       {
            n++;
       }

       printf("input more no.? y or n\n");
       scanf("%c\n", &c);
    } while (c=='y');

    printf("the total count of positive, negative and zeros are %d %d %d\n", p,n,z);

    return 0;
}
```

**Expected result is:**

> enter a no.
>
> 4
>
> input more no.? y or n
>
> y
>
> enter a no.
>
> 3
>
> input more no.? y or n
>
> y
>
> enter a no.
>
> -1
>
> input more no.? y or n
>
> n

the final count of positive, negative and zeros are 2 1 0

**But the actual output coming is:**

> enter a no.
>
> 4
>
> input more no.? y or n
>
> y

the final count of positive, negative and zeros are 1 0 0

Comment: `scanf("%c\n", &c);` --> `scanf(" %c", &c);` The `\n` character in `scanf()` waits for another input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is a combination of two separate problems.

The first is that any white-space characters in a `scanf` format string tells `scanf` to read (and throw away) any consecutive white-space in the input.

But to know where the white-space in the input ends, it needs to see something that is *not* a white-space. That's why trailing space in the format string forces you (the user) to input something else.

The second problem is that for the previous input operation (`scanf("%d", &a)`) you probably pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to "send" the input to the program. This <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be put into the input buffer as a newline (which is a white-space character). When you then read your characters with the `"%c"` format, it will read that newline. You need to skip that newline.

Both problems are solved the same way: Ask `scanf` to read (and throw away) *leading* white-space. Which is done by putting the space at the beginning of the format string, as in

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
//     ^
// Note space here instead
```

Also note that this explicit skipping of leading white-space is only needed for the `"%c"` and `"%["` formats, all other formats do this implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You mix read of a number and read of a character you do not want to get the character enter just after the number being generally a newline, but currently you get that newline.

To bypass the separators (space / newline) just add a space in the format before `%c` and you do not need to specify a newline : `scanf(" %c", &c);`

After that :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter a no.
4
input more no.? y or n
y
enter a no.
3
input more no.? y or n
y
enter a no.
-1
input more no.? y or n
n
the total count of positive, negative and zeros are 2 1 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```